# Kotlin enviromental values

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning kotlin, I stumbled across an [open-source repo](https://github.com/RuneStar/launcher), cloned it and ran on my computer, it is a update tool to update an existing jar, although looking at their code how do they approached to that, they did something like this.

```
    private fun updateJar(frame: LaunchFrame, project: Project) {
    val sourcePath = project.jarSourcePath
    val jarPath = project.jarPath
    val repoName = project.repoName

    frame.log("Reading source URL from '$sourcePath'")
    val sourceUrl = readTextFile(sourcePath)?.let { URI(it) }
    frame.log("Source URL: $sourceUrl")

    frame.log("Connecting to GitHub")
    val github = GitHub.connectAnonymously()

    frame.log("Using repository '$repoName'")
    val repo = github.getRepository(repoName)

    frame.log("Finding latest release")
    val latestRelease = repo.listReleases().first()
    val assets = latestRelease.assets
    check(assets.size == 1) { "Release must only have one asset" }
    val asset = assets.first()
    val downloadUrl = URI(asset.browserDownloadUrl)
    frame.log("Latest URL: $downloadUrl")

    if (sourceUrl == null || sourceUrl != downloadUrl || !verifyJar(jarPath)) {
        frame.log("Downloading '$downloadUrl' to '$jarPath'")
        downloadFile(downloadUrl, jarPath)

        frame.log("Writing '$downloadUrl' to '$sourcePath'")
        writeTextFile(sourcePath, downloadUrl.toString())
    } else {
        frame.log("'$jarPath' is up to date")
    }
}
```

Which looks pretty much straight-forward, but here's the catch, there are no actual URL's for the $sourceUrl and others, can someone shed some light to this question? It starts downloading the repo which is [runestar/client](http://github.com/runestar/client) but there are no actual links for the exact repo what it's trying to download, so how did they do that?

Comment: `val sourceUrl = readTextFile(sourcePath)?.let { URI(it) }` is defined... Where does `sourcePath` come from? How about `project`? Where is this function called from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are being extracted using some logic, scattered around various places in the code.

For example, see https://github.com/RuneStar/launcher/blob/3e8dcb59c32d2818c917705c6c4432f9fc12c449/src/main/java/org/runestar/launcher/RuneStar.kt#L15

`override val repoName: String get() = "RuneStar/client"`

Comment: That doesn't make much difference even after changing the values, it still grabs the old repo url. @PiotrK

Comment: @MikkKüttim the second occurrence of `client` is here: https://github.com/RuneStar/launcher/blob/3e8dcb59c32d2818c917705c6c4432f9fc12c449/src/main/java/org/runestar/launcher/RuneStar.kt#L19 Try changing this one.

Comment: Also, make sure that you rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

It's not environment variables, and it's not downloading from a URL, it's writing to one on the local filesystem.

The `Project` interface sets up the file locations and the `RuneStar` class sets up a specfic Github repository.